# Building Cardano Wallet

Tags: wallet, build

Guys I'm having some error when building cardano-wallet

Error: Could not load module ‘System.Random.Internal’ when building from source.

[image]

Edit: I just followed the tutorial on developers.cardano.org

Found the same issue here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2824

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to run:

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet.git
cd cardano-wallet
git fetch --all --recurse-submodules --tags
git checkout tags/v2021-09-09
cabal configure --with-compiler=ghc-8.10.7 --constraint="random<1.2"
cabal build all -frelease
```